# How to embed a public transit route planner in my website

Tags: iframe, web, directions, transit

I'm looking for some solution for displaying a box in my contact us/about us page in my website that will allow visitors to plan their way to my business using public transit (not car).
I know google has this in their maps website but couldn't find any way to embed something dynamic inside my website code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to [get Google Maps route planner on a website's iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687603/how-to-get-google-maps-route-planner-on-websites-iframe?rq=1).

You can also use Moovit as transit directions provider. They have a widget you can embed in your website with different themes and configuration.

find the documentation here:
https://www.developers.moovitapp.com/directions-web-widget